# Issues with Paw's DynamicValueInput type JSON and Checkbox

Tags: paw-app

I want to create a DynamicValue plugin for Paw generating Json Web Tokens. The full source can be found here: https://github.com/choffmeister/Paw-JsonWebTokenDynamicValue

Relevant file:

```
// JsonWebTokenDynamicValue.js
import jsrsasign from 'jsrsasign';

@registerDynamicValueClass
class JsonWebTokenDynamicValue {
  static identifier = 'de.choffmeister.PawExtensions.JsonWebTokenDynamicValue';
  static title = 'Json Web Token';
  static help = 'https://github.com/choffmeister/Paw-JsonWebTokenDynamicValue';

  static inputs = [
    DynamicValueInput('signatureSecret', 'Secret', 'SecureValue'),
    DynamicValueInput('signatureSecretIsBase64', 'Secret is Base64', 'Checkbox'),
    DynamicValueInput('payload', 'Payload', 'JSON')
  ];

  evaluate() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.payload, null, 2));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.signatureSecretIsBase64, null, 2));

    const now = Math.floor((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

    const header = {
      typ: 'JWT',
      alg: 'HS256'
    };
    const payload = {
      ...this.payload,
      exp: now + (60 * 60 * 24 * 7),
      iat: now
    };

    const secret = this.signatureSecretIsBase64
      ? {b64: jsrsasign.b64utob64(this.signatureSecret)}
      : this.signatureSecret;

    return jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign(null, header, payload, secret);
  }
}
```

How it looks in the GUI:

[image]

I searched https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/extensions/create-dynamic-value, the surrounding documentation and all plugin examples I could find on the web, but I still have two problems I cannot solve:

1. When using the DynamicValueInput of type `Checkbox` then the input field is not visible (see screenshot). I get a value (empty string), but just cannot see it. How can I make the checkbox appear?
2. When using the DynamicValueInput of type `JSON` then used dynamic values inside the JSON (see screenshot) are not resolved, but instead I get kind of a description object (stringified), what this dynamic value is. Logging the `this.payload` object looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "foo": "[{\"data\":{\"environmentVariable\":\"2925ABDA-8AAC-440B-B2CA-DA216CD37A09\"},\"identifier\":\"com.luckymarmot.EnvironmentVariableDynamicValue\"}]"
   }
   ```

   Maybe it is worth to note: When using DynamicInputValue of type `KeyValueList` then the inner dynamic values are resolved properly. How can I achive this with the `JSON` type, too?

Comment: You're right, both issues are clearly bugs. I've been able to reproduce it myself. A fix will be on its way soon! :) Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem. Looking forward to the fix so I can publish my plugin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in [Paw 2.3.3](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.3.3) and @Thekwasti's extension has actually been published here: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/JsonWebTokenDynamicValue